# Lacrosse balls versus using one's own knee to loosen in calf muscles

Tags: stretching, massage, calf-muscles-calves

One may use a Lacrosse balls to loosen calf muscles (i.e., gastronemius and the soleus), e.g.:

[image]

[image]

Couldn't one use one's own knee to loosen in calf muscles instead, just as efficiently as the Lacrosse ball?

Comment: This one would also get better results in Fitness.

Comment: @CareyGregory Answers in fitness tend to be guesses or personal experience. I prefer scientific research.

Comment: There isn't going to be scientific research on lacrosse balls vs knee, or anything similar.  You should perhaps ask a physical therapist as to the benefits of a ball over a stationary similarly shaped object.  I don't think we have a DPT on here currently.

Comment: @DoctorWhom Here is some scientific research on lacrosse balls: [Crisco, J.J., Drewniak, E.I., Alvarez, M.P. and Spenciner, D.B., 2005. Physical and mechanical properties of various field lacrosse balls. Journal of applied biomechanics, 21(4), pp.383-393.](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/9063/b28e4cbe221fc194394368f2efe0ee32a7aa.pdf) Maybe some studies have used knees instead.

Comment: My doubts are that anyone would go to the trouble of comparing one simple inexpensive modality vs another very similar one that accomplishes almost the same thing.  Like lacrosse ball vs tennis ball also would unlikely be done.  But I could be wrong; I'm not familiar with the literature in this area.

Comment: As @DoctorWhom pointed out, who would fund a study to answer a question like this? Answer: nobody. Now, who might actually have some insight into the question? I think the answer is the folks who live, eat and breath this stuff over in Fitness.SE.